# Install multiple Node.js Modules based on dependencies (list)

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line, npm

I have a dependencies list of nearly 40 node modules and while I was able to install all of them using one (or two) commands-

> npm install module-1 module-2 ... module-N --save-dev

-still looking for a way to create a file that installs all dependencies when executed. This way anyone could download a single file for his/her system (Mac / Linux in my case) and install all modules by simply running that file. Any great suggestion, method? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm init` will create a package.json for you. Within that file you can list your app's dependencies and dev dependencies like this:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.9.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "mocha": "^2.0.1"
    }
}
```

Then `npm install`

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, figured out what was wrong, `sudo npm install`

Comment: And gyp fails with node v0.12.2 :( but at least you put me back in the right direction. Thanks again!